# How to combine several API Gateways?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

In my project I got two or more API gateways which are calling to lambda functions.
Currently all the API Gateways are used as Controllers and the lambda functions as services.

The next step in this architecture is to use on top all API Gateways another API Gateway/Lambda function which will call all the API by given parameters.

I wonder to know if this kind of approach is a best practice or is there another AWS service which can solve my solution ?

Comment: Not sure I follow, why would you want to use multiple API Gateways? If you want to accept requests from outside, in most cases a single API Gateway should be sufficient.
If you need to trigger multiple Lambda functions from a single API Gateway call, you might want to look at the Step functions (API Gateway->Lambda function->Step function job)

Answer (score 0):

(1) You can combine multiple API Gateways by writing code to call another API GW in a Lambda function.

(2) You call invoke Lambda functions directly in a Lambda function with sync and async manners.

```
response = client.invoke(
  FunctionName='my-function',
  Payload='{}',
  Qualifier='1',
)
```

[functions-calling-functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJUzI.png)

(3) You can organize function workflow using StepFunctions

[using step functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WR6Wf.png)

(4) You can also use SQS, SNS and EventBridge to apply push/poll, fan-out patterns or to design with event-driven architecture